# Resolving Dependancys on Eclipse Plug-in with Maven / Junit

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, eclipse-plugin

So I'm trying to integrate a Junit test on an eclipse plug-in into my maven build. The test is contained in a fragment project, while the plug in is obviously just a plug-in project. The test plug in depends on the plug-in project. But when I run a

```
clean install
```

using m2e in eclipse, I get the following error:

```
Missing requirement: com.simple.plugin 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

I've been playing around with this for a while now and cannot figure it out. I want to keep the test separate from the plug-in if at all possible. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using tycho to resolve your osgi dependencies?

Comment: Yes, though I don't see any noticeable changes. I'm including the tycho plugin in both POM files. How would one recommend structuring the whole thing? Should each plug in required (ie referenced in a dependency somewhere) have ALL of the info in the POM file? I tried the module / parent structure to no avail due to our generated build server.

Comment: When using tycho, you don't specify dependencies in the pom. Rather, you specify them in the MANIFEST.MF file as a standard OSGi bundle.